# Scratching the color off a picture

Tags: c#, wpf, inkcanvas

I'm working on a project with the kinect (I'm adding in case someone has a good way to do using the kinect) but I think this is mostly some programming issue in C# and WPF. I want to make to have 2 pictures, one on top of the other and with a mouse click, be able to scratch the first picture out. I tried using inkcanvas and put the picture in the inkcanvas but I can only draw on top of it.

Can someone give me an idea or some methods he think it would be better way to proceed?

Comment: It's weird but every time I try and to put Hi everyone in the start, it gets remove out of the post :(... 
Hi Everyone :)

Comment: That's the way things work here, see [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: @jimmy_keen Thanks :), At least I can say 'Thanks'

Comment: @adlescouflair: I doubt it.

Comment: @H.B. you're right,.. I just saw that my thanks was removed

Comment: @adlescouflair: That was me; i removed it as i remove all clutter and then saw your comment about it. Everyone appreciates people being nice but this platform is optimized for getting information quickly, hence no formalities and no undirected discussion, just questions and answers. Also if you want to be nice: People will appreciate it more if a question is clear, shows effort and gives all the necessary information to answer it. A bad question won't be saved by "hi" and "thanks".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idea might be using an [`OpacityMask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.opacitymask.aspx) which is a [`VisualBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualbrush.aspx) that contains your `InkCanvas`.

Comment: Thank you,  but what's a visual brush ? what is the between the other brushes ?  
I think I'm getting there... Now I have a scratch card like a lottery ticket.  
http://geekswithblogs.net/tkokke/archive/2009/03/02/scratchcard-in-wpf.aspx
I was testing this code found on the link I just add and I wonder how I can make a picture be the visual brush and not having a gray visual brush. I tried changing it but then, I see I can't scratch it off.  
:(  why don't Microsoft add a small sentence in their page to tell the use of class at, least I may know what it is :(

Comment: @adlescouflair: You should just need to put your other image beneath the one affected by the mask, then it should show by default, the other one shows when drawn on the canvas. The gray comes from the background of the `Grid`, add your image as first element of said `Grid`. (Just make sure you have the images in the right order)

Comment: I'm a bit lost, I have some electricity issues... I'll try to understand more tomorrow or later if I get electricity. Thank again for your help

Comment: Thank you :D It works ! I actually put the picture I want to display as the background of the grid...  
But now can you explain to me why it works. I don't like not understanding it things I put in my code :(

Comment: Well, the `Grid` background is shown by default, the image with the `OpacityMask` is shown where the mask is not transparent, this is determined by the `InkCanvas` in the mask, so if you draw on it the image becomes visible.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did, Thanks @HB for your help.  part of the code comes from 
http://geekswithblogs.net/tkokke/archive/2009/03/02/scratchcard-in-wpf.aspx if anyone wants to know or need it.

```
<Border Background="#FF909090" BorderBrush="#FF000000" 
     BorderThickness="2,2,2,2">
        <Grid Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
            <Grid.Background>
               <ImageBrush ImageSource="birthday_cake_by_protoperahe.jpg"/>
            </Grid.Background>
            <InkCanvas x:Name="inkCanvas" 
                Background="{x:Null}">
                <InkCanvas.DefaultDrawingAttributes>
                    <DrawingAttributes Height="25" Width="25"/>
                </InkCanvas.DefaultDrawingAttributes>
            </InkCanvas>
            <Image IsHitTestVisible="False" Source="planet.jpg" Stretch="Fill">
                <Image.OpacityMask>
                    <VisualBrush 
                 Visual="{Binding ElementName=inkCanvas}"/>
                </Image.OpacityMask>
            </Image>

        </Grid>
```